# How to build gridview with custom width in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

Based on the child width grid view should be built.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about how much items can have in a row, you can use the [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) , it's really simple.

A example from docs, you can use a list too.

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: <Widget>[
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('AH')),
      label: Text('Hamilton'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('ML')),
      label: Text('Lafayette'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('HM')),
      label: Text('Mulligan'),
    ),
    Chip(
      avatar: CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900, child: Text('JL')),
      label: Text('Laurens'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Nice Answer Bro

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using a `SliverGrid` with `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent`.

- You can change the `maxCrossAxisExtent` to give the max width of each child.
- Then you can also change `childAspectRatio` to specify the height in relation to the width. (eg. `childAspectRatio` = 4.0 means 1/4 units tall for every unit in wide)

Below is an example from the [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html#widgets.SliverGrid.1). Also here's the example on a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/3e6362ab2d60a15219df73759a1465f4?null_safety=true).

```
SliverGrid(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    childAspectRatio: 4.0,
  ),
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.teal[100 * (index % 9)],
        child: Text('grid item $index'),
      );
    },
    childCount: 20,
  ),
)
```